# Programmatically created button doesn't response to user's click

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I know that this kind of issue discussed several times here but, I have already searched and tried without success. I am trying to create a simple login view on the top of general menu. This login page contains 2 textfields(username & password) and 1 button(login). My problem is that while everything appears perfectly when I click on Login button, is not responding.

**The login view animated from start to end point using moveTo method. Comment that part but still not responding.*

Main.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    if (![prefs objectForKey:@"userName"]) {
        LoginScreen *login = [[LoginScreen alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(35, 400, 250, 350)];
        [self.view addSubview:login];
        [login moveTo:CGPointMake(35.0, 65.0) duration:0.6 option:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut];  
    }        

    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

LoginScreen.m

```
@synthesize login;

    - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
    {
         self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
         if (self) {

             self.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
             self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

             [self addButton:login withTitle:@"Login" andSize:CGRectMake(85, 200, 90, 35)];
             [login addTarget:self action:@selector(attemptLogin)
                   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

         }

         return self;
    }

        - (void) addButton: (UIButton*) button withTitle: (NSString*) title andSize: (CGRect) size{

            button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
            button.frame = size;
            [button setTitle:title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            button.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
            [self addSubview:button];
        }


        - (void)attemptLogin{

            NSString *user = usernameTxt.text;
            NSString *pass = passwordTxt.text;
            NSString *url = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"http://domain.com/login.php?username=%@&password=%@", user, pass];

            NSLog(@"%@", url);

        }
```

Nothing print on screen.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Keyword: C passes function arguments by value, not by reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is mainly you are allocting a new button, therefore not working with your login button, I commented the allocation on your code and this should work:

//Old version of code removed, please check edit

**Edit**

```
  - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {

        self.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
        self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

        login = [self addButtonWithTitle:@"Login" andSize:CGRectMake(85, 200, 90, 35)];
        [login addTarget:self action:@selector(attemptLogin)
        forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    }

    return self;
}

- (UIButton) addButtonWithTitle: (NSString*) title andSize: (CGRect) size{

    button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    button.frame = size;
    [button setTitle:title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [self addSubview:button];
    return button;
}


- (void)attemptLogin{

    NSString *user = usernameTxt.text;
    NSString *pass = passwordTxt.text;
    NSString *url = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"http://domain.com/login.php?username=%@&password=%@", user, pass];

    NSLog(@"%@", url);

}
```

Comment: yes login is an IBOutlet. To be honest, didn't understand your explanation. I am sending the 'login' button as parameter to that method. Why to remove that line of initialisation?

Comment: @PanayiotisNicolaou That's beacuse the login button is already initialized on the interface builder (nib or storyboard) so you are deleting whatever you placed on your interface, and since you previously added the target action that also gets erased, so after you do the initialization you are basically erasing all previous properties, you are technically working on a new login button :)

Comment: To see what I mean print the pointers to the same button before and after your add button method, you'll notice different pointers for the same login button, use NSLog(@"Login button pointer %p",login);

Comment: I am not using storyboard/nib. Create it using code. The problem seems to be the addTarget method. Move it inside addButton and now is responding. Thanks for your time :) Really, really fast reply!!! Surprised

Comment: @PanayiotisNicolaou that was another solution :) but I didn't knew if you wanted to be attaching to the button on that method, because now that method is not that generic and might only work for the login unless you modify the method again :P You are welcome :)

Comment: As you can see on sergio's answer above, I am mentioning the same thing. Either pass the selector as parameter (I don't know how you are passing methods as parameters :p) or I can modify attemptLogin and have if-statements checking tag number. What do you think?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23327/discussion-between-perrohunter-and-panayiotis-nicolaou)

Answer (score 2):

This is because you created a button without specifying what selector to call when the button is clicked. Adding this line to your `addButton` method will fix the problem:

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(attemptLogin) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

When you try doing the same through the synthesized `login` property, the code does not work, because you never set `login`. When you pass it to the `addButton` function, the value gets ignored (you re-assign it right away). The assignment never changes the value of `login`, though, because Objective C passes parameters by value.

An alternative way to fix your code is to pass a pointer to `login`, rather than `login` itself, like this:

```
- (void) addButton: (UIButton**) button withTitle: (NSString*) title andSize: (CGRect) size {
    *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    (*button).frame = size;
    [*button setTitle:title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    (*button).userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [self addSubview:*button];
}
```

I would recommend against this way of fixing your code: using `login` directly inside `addButton` would probably be a better choice.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you meant:

```
- (void) addButton: (UIButton*) button withTitle: (NSString*) title andSize: (CGRect) size{

    button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    button.frame = size;
    [button setTitle:title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
     [button addTarget:self action:@selector(attemptLogin)
           forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self addSubview:button];
}
```

You should also remove that:

```
     [login addTarget:self action:@selector(attemptLogin)
           forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

from the init method.

Comment: Didn't expect so fast reply! You are right, that solve the problem. However, what can I do if in the future want to add more buttons? Every button will trigger attemptLogin. Thanks :)